# Outside cap for exhaust fan

Tags: exhaust

What is the best cap to use for a thru-wall bathroom exhaust fan install? The ducting is 4" smooth aluminum.

Winters here are brutal. I'm concerned about wind sucking the cap flaps open, letting in cold air. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent cold air from dropping down my bath fan duct?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/211565/how-can-i-prevent-cold-air-from-dropping-down-my-bath-fan-duct)

Answer (score 1):

I have two bath fans that are the inline style, 1 for each bathroom. one fan is 4" solid duct end to end, the more powerful uses a 6" solid duct end to end.

From the vent side in the bathroom ceiling, there is a butterfly damper that remains closed due to gravity and lifts up when the bath vent is turned on. On the exhaust side, the 4" bath fan has a plastic hooded exhaust cap, while the 6" duct has a plastic louvered cap.

I would say on very windy days, my 4" duct probably opens up, as I can hear my damper lift up and down sometimes.

I also recently installed a new dryer duct, 4" diameter, where I used a heavier gauge exhaust cap which is damper style, with magnets. This cap could probably work for a bath fan, as long as the fan is powerful enough to lift up the damper flap. I used [this one](https://dryerwallvent.com/).

I would try adding a damper inline and a beefier exhaust cap.